# How to use Swift's new Async/Await features with Firestore Listeners

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I just want an example of how Swifts new `async/await` concurrency features can be used to rewrite a common Firestore listener method like the one below.

```
func listen(for user: User, completion: (Result<CurrentUser, Error>) -> Void) {
        db.collection("Users")
            .document(user.uid)
            .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { document, error in
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(.networkError)
                } else {
                    guard let document = document else {
                        completion(.failure(.operationFailure)
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        guard let profile = try document.data(as: Profile.self, with: .estimate) else {
                            completion(.failure(.operationFailure)
                            return
                        }
                        completion(CurrentUser(user, profile: profile))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(.operationFailure)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that this is a good use case for async await as adding a snapshot listener creates a stream of data rather than a single response. It's a much better candidate for using a Combine publisher/subscriber. Rather than having a function `listen` that takes a completion block you could have a function that returns a Subscription. I did something similar using TheComposableArchitecture. I'll see if I can add an answer.

Comment: Adding to @Fogmeister's comment: IMHO, "completion" is also not a suitable name for your original function. A "completion" should execute once, and only once. If the closure can be called several times, naming the handler "notification" would have been better IMHO.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thats actually something that never crossed my mind, glad you brought it up. Thanks :)

Comment: @Fogmeister late to the thread, but there is `AsyncSequence` which appears to be a (somewhat limited) combine alternative

Comment: @atultw yeah, more recently I’ve written my own similar cache/subscribe structure using an AsyncStream which worked really well. I learned a ton more about Async Await also. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, like I said in my comment I don't think this is the right use case for Async/Await. Async/Await is more suited to asynchronous functions where you would receive back a single response. For instance a REST api that returns some value.

Incidentally, the Firestore function `.getDocument()` now has async/await alternatives.

However, the `addSnapshotListener` is something that will return multiple values over time and call the callback function over and over again.

What we can do with this, though, is to turn it into a Combine Publisher.

Here I've created a small `FirestoreSubscription` struct that you can use to subscribe to a document path...

```
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FirestoreSubscription {
  static func subscribe(id: AnyHashable, docPath: String) -> AnyPublisher<DocumentSnapshot, Never> {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<DocumentSnapshot, Never>()
    
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().document(docPath)
    let listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
      if let snapshot = snapshot {
        subject.send(snapshot)
      }
    }
    
    listeners[id] = Listener(document: docRef, listener: listener, subject: subject)
    
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
  
  static func cancel(id: AnyHashable) {
    listeners[id]?.listener.remove()
    listeners[id]?.subject.send(completion: .finished)
    listeners[id] = nil
  }
}

private var listeners: [AnyHashable: Listener] = [:]
private struct Listener {
  let document: DocumentReference
  let listener: ListenerRegistration
  let subject: PassthroughSubject<DocumentSnapshot, Never>
}
```

The `subscribe` function returns an `AnyPublisher<DocumentSnapshot, Never>` (so currently it doesn't handle any errors.

I also created a `FirestoreDecoder` that will decode `DocumentSnapshot` into my own `Codable` types...

```
import Firebase

struct FirestoreDecoder {
    static func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> (DocumentSnapshot) -> T? where T: Decodable {
        { snapshot in
            try? snapshot.data(as: type)
        }
    }
}
```

I created a really simple Firestore document...

[image]

And a struct that we will decode from that document...

```
struct LabelDoc: Codable {
  let value: String?
}
```

Now in my `ViewController` I can subscribe to that document path and decode and set it onto a label...

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
  
  var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
  
  struct SubscriptionID: Hashable {}
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    FirestoreSubscription.subscribe(id: SubscriptionID(), docPath: "labels/title")
      .compactMap(FirestoreDecoder.decode(LabelDoc.self))
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .map(\LabelDoc.value)
      .assign(to: \.text, on: label)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

This is just a quick example project so there may be better ways of doing this but now I can update the value in Firestore and it will immediately update on the screen

You could probably even wrap up that subscription into a function that could be used in multiple places.

Comment: @otymartin Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you for the detailed and comprehensive answer with working example. Really helps gives a birds eye of where async/await is appropriate and where it isn't and how to go about handling this edge case. 

Comment: @otymartin no worries. Happy to be able to help. 

Comment: Firebase has support for Combine now - see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseCombineSwift/Sources/Firestore/Query%2BCombine.swift